# Make rspec 1.3 work while 2.4 is installed?

Tags: rspec

I have a Rails 2.3.X project I'm working on.  On my system, I have various versions of rspec, too:

rspec (2.4.0, 1.3.1)
rspec-core (2.4.0)
rspec-expectations (2.4.0)
rspec-mocks (2.4.0)
rspec-rails (2.4.1, 1.3.3, 1.3.1)

However:

```
 > spec _1.3.1_ spec/
 Missing these required gems:
 rspec-rails
```

Comment: Removing rspec 2.4 fixes the problem, but... I need it for other projects!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install rvm and create different [gemset](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/) for the wo projects. You can have seperate [rvmrc](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/workflow/rvmrc/) for these projects.

Comment: Yeah, this is also recommended under [No. 3 - Use per-project gemsets on RVM Best Practices](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/best-practices/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use bundler on your 2.3.x project (See http://gembundler.com/rails23.html). Then, after specifying the version you want in the `Gemfile`, just prepend `bundle exec` to any command you run -- that'll force it to use the bundled version instead of the newest system-wide version.